Running Child Function Slower Than Class Function
When comparing the following two solutions to the Reverse Linked List Leetcode, consistently solution 1 (with two class functions) is faster then solution 2 (with 1 class function and 1 child function).
Can anyone help explain why this would be?
Solution 1:
class Solution {
    var prev: ListNode? = nil
    func reverseList(_ head: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
        recurse(head)
        return prev
    }
    func recurse(_ node: ListNode?){
        guard let current = node else { return }
        let next = current.next
        current.next = prev
        prev = current
        recurse(next)
    }
}

Solution 2:
class Solution {
    var prev: ListNode? = nil
    func reverseList(_ head: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
        func recurse(_ node: ListNode?){
            guard let current = node else { return }
            let next = current.next
            current.next = prev
            prev = current
            recurse(next)
        }
        recurse(head)
        return prev
    }
}


How did you measure the performance? If you're saying based on the Leetcode's runtime environment, it's inconsistent and you get different results every time you run the same code.

You'd need to know details of the JS interpreter to say for sure, but it's at least possible top level functions have inherently lower overhead. Btw, the implementation is needlessly complex. For example, the tail call to recurse() (in both implementations) is superfluous and probably makes the code slower than the obvious loop.

Yes measured performance with Leetcode but ran it about 10 times and consistently solution 1 was about x2 faster than solution 2.

@Gene I solved it using loop also but practicing with recursion as well

@brunshte Did you benchmark? If you're relying on LeetCode's benchmark, that's completely inconsistent and fully unreliable.

@user24714692 would love to try. what do you suggest? How to benchmark it? Thanks.

@brunshte Benchmarking in isolation is pretty complicated. But you could just run each function, some 10 million times, on a local machine to see what the difference would be. I don't think this is important. But if you do, go ahead. See here for instance. Note that when you submit the same code to LeetCode over and over again, LeetCode uses caching and brings you similar result back. But, generally LeetCode runs on a cloud and they do not want to benchmark every submission based on milliseconds accuracy..

@Gene hate to nitpick but this is Swift not JavaScript.
